# Thread 1: signal SIGABRT libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException (lldb)

Tags: swift

I began programming in swift this week and am trying to make a simple navigation bar in my app. It's not the first time I meet this error and no idea what can be missing. If I'm not mistaken I hook everything from the ui to the code correctrly , but the output says:

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException (lldb)
```

What can be the mistake? Thanks

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
var t = Timer()
@IBAction func hi(_ sender: Any) {
    print("Camera button pressed")
    t.invalidate()
}

func processTimer() {
    print("1 second has passed")
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    t = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: Selector(("processTimer")), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with the `minus10Button` that is linked to numerous IBActions - some of which didn't exist. So right click on the `minus10Button` in the Interface Builder and removed the old and irrelevant links, fixing the problem.

Comment: changed it, but still not works, full code: https://pastebin.com/4bFR2bvM

Comment: Edited the answer try it.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help, I'm very grateful!

Comment: Its my pleasure!